# Affine Sets Covering a Prevariety are Open

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Right now in my algebraic geometry class we are learning about prevarieties. I know that by definition, a prevariety is a set that can be covered by affine varieties. My question is, why do we specify that the affine varieties that cover this prevariety are "open?" Does it have to do with the topology that we put on the prevariety? If anyone could shed some light on this I would appreciate it.

Comment: Think about manifolds: we define a manifold to be something that locally looks like $\Bbb R^n$, in the sense that it has a collection of open sets that are each homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$. We're saying here that we define a prevariety to be something that looks locally like an affine variety, in that there's a collection of open sets that are each isomorphic to an affine variety as varieties. It's exactly the same idea.

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense. Since the topology on the prevariety contains exactly the subsets that have inverse image (under the embedding of the affine varieties) open in the respective affine varieties, of course this implies that the varieties (or more strictly their images in the prevariety), are open. Thanks, this really cleared things up